# How to get the image file path from the input file thats is inside Modal component in angular 2-4 and angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How I can take the image path from an input file element.

#### modal.html

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="dialogRef.close(form.value)" ngNativeValidate>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="8px">

    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px" class="example-full-width">
      <md-input-container class="example-full-width">
        <input mdInput ngModel name="title" placeholder="Title" required>
      </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container class="example-full-width">
        <input type="number" mdInput ngModel name="price" placeholder="Price" required>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <!-- IMAGE -->
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="8px" style="padding-right:20px;">
      <input id="imgForNewProsfora" type="file" ngModel name="image" class="dropify" data-height="200" />
    </div>

  <md-dialog-actions align="left">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <button md-button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close()">Cancel</button>
      <button md-button color="accent">Save User</button>
    </div>
  </md-dialog-actions>

</form>
```

### The component where I get the data from the modal component

typescript

```
openDialogAddProsfora() {

    this.dialogAddProsfora.open(DialogAddProsforaComponent).afterClosed()
      .filter(result => !!result)
      .subscribe(prosfora => {

        if (prosfora) {

          let prosfora2 = {
            title : prosfora.title,
            description: prosfora.description,
            price: prosfora.price,
            time_created : this.getCurentTime(),
            time_updated: this.getCurentTime()
          };

        }


      });

  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can bind it directly to file input. You can do this. I created a mock-up plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/QewqaGmxwbt2NvO6fOWj?p=preview

```
<input id="imgForNewProsfora" type="file" ngModel name="image" class="dropify" data-height="200" (change)="fileChange($event)" />

fileChange(e){
    this.image = e.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

So you need to pass the variable as a part of `close()` method as below

```
<md-dialog-actions align="left">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <button md-button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close(name)">Cancel</button> 
      <button md-button color="accent">Save User</button>
    </div>
  </md-dialog-actions>
```

And you have the value in the subscription

```
this.dialogAddProsfora.open(DialogAddProsforaComponent).afterClosed()
      .subscribe(prosfora => { console.log(prosfora) })
```

Comment: I don't call the modal from my parent component from HTML file I have function that opens the modal how i can pass the ``` <modal-name (filePath)="handleEvent($event)"> </modal-name> ```

Comment: Updated the post.